# automatically select feature after drawend

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I have a `Select` and `Draw` interaction in openlayers 3 (v3.9.0) and I'd like to add some unique behavior to it.  Currently, after a `feature` is drawn, I have to click on the `feature` to `select` it.  Is there a way to bypass the `click` event altogether and have the feature auto select itself on `drawend`?

Thanks

Comment: Choose an answer as correct, to not remain unresolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.  `ol.interaction.select` fires AFTER the `draw.on('drawend',())` resolves itself.  The trick is to force select.condition to return false after a new feature has been added.  See the use of `selectedFeature.push(evt.feature)` and `var featureadded` in my jsfiddle for details.

http://jsfiddle.net/williemaddox/0um2ud3v/

Answer (score 2):

You can simply call `getFeatures()` on the `ol.interaction.Select` then add the new feature to this observable collection:

```
selectCtrl = new ol.interaction.Select();
drawCtrl = new ol.interaction.Draw();

drawCtrl.on("drawend",function(e){
      selectCtrl.getFeatures();
      features.push(e.feature);
});
```

Comment: This only works if the cursor is directly over the feature when drawend is fired.

Answer (score 1):

If, like me, you also want to automatically leave drawing mode and return to selection mode after the drawing ends (and the feature is selected), you can do something like this:

```
mySelect = new ol.interaction.Select();
myDraw = new ol.interaction.Draw();
lastDrawnFeature = null;

myDraw.on('drawend',function(e){
    lastDrawnFeature = e.feature;

    // switch to select interaction
    myDraw.setActive(false);
    mySelect.setActive(true);
});

mySelect.on('select',function(e){
    if (lastDrawnFeature) {
        // Actual selection has to be done here,
        // otherwise the last point drawn will be selected instead.
        mySelect.getFeatures();
        features.clear();
        features.push(lastDrawnFeature);
        lastDrawnFeature = null;
    }
});
```